# Get effective permissions for user in Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure

In a Resource Group Access Control (IAM) you can Check Access for a user, group, service principal or MI on that RG. This check also seems to be able to list access even if the user being searched for is nested inside a group. Is there a powershell equivalent to do the same?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 0):

ok...it can be done by

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <String> -ExpandPrincipalGroups
```

The -ExpandPrincipalGroups switch only seems to work at the subscription  level(but will enumerate at the RG level automatically) and the ObjectId cannot be a service principal